# Достать или считать? js - setInterval

Tags: javascript, count

Есть ли способ узнать количество итераций функции `setInterval` без использования дополнительной переменной?

Чтобы вместо

```
var count = 0;

setInterval(function(){count++;},1000);
```

было как

```
var iid = setInterval(function(){console.log("hello world");},1000);
//проходит некоторое время
var count = getIntervalCount(iid);
```

Comment: нет. только если написать свою реализацию с включением подобного метода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что стандартных средств нет. Но всегда можно написать свои обёртки:

```
function mySetInterval(func, tmt){
    var retObj={"counter":0};
    retObj["realInterval"]=
    setInterval(function (){retObj.counter++; func();}, tmt);
    return retObj;
}

function myClearInterval(obj){
    clearInterval(obj.realInterval);
}

function getIntervalCount(obj){
    return obj.counter;
}
```

Если нужны дополнительные параметры, передаваемые в функцию, можно изменить функцию `mySetInterval` так:

```
function mySetInterval(func, tmt, ...args){
    var retObj={"counter":0};
    retObj["realInterval"]=
    setInterval(function (){retObj.counter++; func(...args);}, tmt);
    return retObj;
}
```

Comment: Боже мой, какая дичь. Интересно, что было сказано без использования дополнительных переменных и приняли этот ответ

Comment: @Yuri, _стандартных средств нет._, далее просто идет workaround

Comment: @Yuri ну так тут вроде нет дополнительных переменных. Только дополнительные функции.

Comment: @Imieee, реализация интересна. Спасибо большое за дополнительную информацию.